# Saving Information Between Executions?

Tags: c, file

this is my first time here so apologies for anything that requires apologizing for.

I have a program that saves text into a separate file and will save after the execution is complete. My problem is that due to the nature of fprintf, the function we were taught to use, every time I re-run the program, anything I input into that file gets erased and replaced.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

My code so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    FILE *Mem_r;
    FILE *Mem_w;
    char word[257];
    char comp = 'n';
    int count, ret = 1;

    Mem_w = fopen("Memory_w.txt", "w");
    Mem_r = fopen("Memory_r.c", "r");

    if (Mem_w != NULL && Mem_r != NULL) {

        printf("What do you want me to remember?\n");

        scanf("%s", &word);

        fprintf(Mem_w, "%s ", &word);
    }
    else {
        printf("Error");
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Would you paste the code what you have done so far, then it would be easier to see what problem your facing?

Comment: Yoyr problem has nothing to do with `fprintf()`, it is related to how the file is opened. According to `fopen()` documentation, opening an existing file in `"w"` mode is required to discard contents and, from there, behave as if starting from a newly created file.   That is the mode you're using so the behaviour you're seeing is what you have coded.   If you want different behaviour, look at the documentation for other modes that `fopen()` supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your code like this.

```
Mem_w = fopen("Memory_w.txt", "a");
```

> use the `a` option instead of `w`, as the `w` will instruct the stream to discard the file to be opened. Just as @Peter commented.